# How do I index the last element in a Redux store through a Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, redux, cypress, e2e-testing

What I'm trying to do is check for a value that is located at the nth index of some array in a Redux store.

```
    it('Enter text into comments, send comment, verify comment is displayed in comment list', ()=>{
        cy.server()
        cy.get('#call-input').type("Where are you?")
        cy.get('#send-btn').click()
        cy.route('POST', '/api/1/call/chatlog/1001/comment').as('sendComment')
        cy.window().its('store').invoke('getState').its('comments').its('data')

    })

})
```

Every time the test runs it will add a new comment to a chat log and I need to check to make sure that comment exists in redux. The comment will be located at the very last index of the array give here.

```
        cy.window().its('store').invoke('getState').its('comments').its('data')
```

I just can't for the life of me figure out out to access the last index and check if the value matches the

```
.type("Where are you?")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using ”then”? Untested:

```
 cy.window()
    .its('store')
    .invoke('getState')
    .its('comments.data')
    .then((data) => {
       cy.wrap(data[data.length - 1])
    })
    .should('eq', 'Where are you?’)
```